# How to replace bbcode tags with attributes

Tags: php, regex

My shared server recently upgraded to php5.4, which broke PEAR HTMLBBcode.

I've tried to write a small function to replace the parser of some simple bbcode, with some code I found on a few forums.

The bbcode I want to parse includes tags such as the image tag with attributes:

```
[img src="" h="" w="" alt=""]
[*] //for bulleted lists
```

As my knowledge of regex is limited, maybe someone can explain how to add attributes to the `img` lines? I assume the `@` is to suppress errors from preg_replace() ?

How would you handle this tag [ * ] ?

```
// original function
function bbCode($string) {
    $search = array(    
        '@\[(?i)img\](.*?)\[/(?i)img\]@si',
        '@\[url\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*\](.*?)\[\/url\]@si'
    );
    $replace = array(
        '<img src="\\1">',
        '<a href="\\1">\\2</a>'
    );
    return preg_replace($search , $replace, $string);
}
```

```
// test
function bbCode($string) {
    $search = array(    
        '@\[img\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*\
         \s*=[(0-9)+]
         \s*=[(0-9)+]
         \s*=\s*(.*?)\s*\]
         (.*?)\[\/img\]@si',
        '[*]'
    );
    $replace = array(
        '<img src="\\1" height="\\2" width="\\3" alt="\\4">',
        '<li></li>'
    );
    return preg_replace($search , $replace, $string);
}
```

Comment: `My shared server recently upgraded to php5.2` which version did you have before? I strongly recommend you to look for another hosting (php 5.4+). Anyways, `@` are regex delimiters, you could even use `#` or `/` instead. I'm also amazed by the creativity of the author, adding `(?i)` all over the places while it's set later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex needed to solve these issues requires a closer examination. The PEAR bbcode library is already ahead many steps in that direction.

Although there are still minor problems with the PEAR library, it is still better than what we were attempting here.

I added the path in php.ini and it returned errors for some reason

```
require "/path/to/pear";
```

My host support was able to fix the reference simply by

```
include "../path/to/pear_bbcode";
```

Answer (score 0):

Square Brackets are special characters in regular expressions used for creating groups. The asterisk is also a regular expression directive as well. Both need to be escaped if you are trying to match literal content. You would want to change your test code to something like this. But make sure to test my suggestion since I am doing it off the cuff and didn't confirm it first.

```
// test
function bbCode($string) {
    $search = array(    
        '@\[img\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*\
         \s*=[(0-9)+]
         \s*=[(0-9)+]
         \s*=\s*(.*?)\s*\]
         (.*?)\[\/img\]@si',
        '\[\*\]'
    );
    $replace = array(
        '<img src="\\1" height="\\2" width="\\3" alt="\\4">',
        '<li></li>'
    );
    return preg_replace($search , $replace, $string);
}
```